# MySQL - Connecting two tables via a Join table - Do all 3 tables need to use the InnoDB engine?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. Classes and students.
I want to create a table which holds two columns class_ID and student_ID.
My question ,as a mySQL noob, is do all 3 tables need to be set as innoDB so tha I can benefit from cascades if say a student or a class is deleted?
Many thanks.

Comment: It would appear that yes I do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would indeed seem that all tables must be  of type innoDB.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that you'll need to use InnoDB to get support for foreign keys. However, you don't need foreign keys to do cascading deletes as MySQL supports multi-table delete statements. Admittedly, foreign keys simplify things nicely and are probably the way to go.